# only 377 of 2085 Pages in PagesLibrary get crawled (SP2010)

Tags: 2010, search, crawling, index

Recently the search does not crawl all pages in the various Pages Libraries in our SharePoint 2010 based Extranet. For example, in our German Technical Catalog which consists of 2085 Pages only 377 items get crawled.
[image: SharePoint Designer - Pages Library - 2085Items]
[image: Central Administration - Search Log 377 Items on Search per URL]

The pages get generated automatically and have the same schema. Except for some values inside an XML file, they are basically the same. 
There are no errors in the Crawl Log that could point to any problem. The strange thing is that the Technical Cataloge for Italy is fully crawled. All 2000+ items are crawled within the Index.
[image: Italian Cataloge - >2000 Items in Index]

I can't detect any reason for this error.

Answer (score 0):

The extranet of our company is too large to get crawled. The Search Service Application and a few other timer job conflicted here. The Search Service Application was interuppted by other timer jobs and so skipped files.